# Why Moon is not falling on Sun (Hill's sphere)?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, moon

The Hill's radius of Earth in Earth-Moon system calculated by formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere is **58212 km**

But the distance between Moon and Earth is **384,400 km**

So, why Moon is not falling on Sun if it is located outside the Hill's sphere? Is there a mistake in Wikipedia? Should I use Earth's semi-major axis instead of Moon's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From that wiki page:

> "The Hill sphere for Earth thus extends out to about 1.5 million km (0.01 AU). The Moon's orbit, at a distance of 0.384 million km from Earth, is comfortably within the gravitational sphere of influence of Earth and it is therefore not at risk of being pulled into an independent orbit around the Sun."

Comment: Hmmm. So, should I put into formula Earth-Sun params instead of Earth-Moon to find is moon inside or outside that sphere?

Comment: @Robotex Should it depend rather on Sun/Earth or Earth/Moon ? (rhetorical question)

Comment: I need to place a moon in my solar system model and trying to find range of allowed distances. Right now it left orbit of earth and go to the orbit of sun